# Adb sideload flashing file type recovery or fastboot

Tags: rom-flashing

I want to flash rom through Adb sideload I am confused with zip.file used in sideload. is it recovery file or fastboot file?
I am downloaded both from
https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/miui/lavender/stable/V11.0.9.0.PFGINXM/

Answer (score 0):

adb is unrelated to fastboot, you can either run adb commands with usb-debugging enabled in boot mode, or adb sideload command in recovery mode. fastboot commands work with fastboot mode only (no adb commands accepted) and requires unlocked bootloader